# What is faster for CSS, select through input[type="whatever"] or #whatever

Tags: css, css-selectors

When selecting form elements what is faster for CSS?

```css
input[type="whatever"]
```

or

```css
#whatever
```

or even

```css
.whatever
```

Comment: Selecting by a uniqueid is as fast as is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selection by id is the fasted so `#whatever`

But unless your form has thousands of element, CSS should have no problem parsing intime either `.class` or `input[type=".."]` rules.

Also if you have multiple elements, it is better to use `.class` or `input[type="whatever"]` for all elements that share the styling than using that many `id` on elements and css rules..

Answer (score 0):

`#whatever` selector is generally faster because of browser implementation (and it resolves into a single element)

see https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering?hl=it or http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/ for further reference about selector efficiency

Comment: That's not why it's fastest

Comment: Thanks, and special thanks for the links for further reference. =)